# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is not working for space i.e, " " in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
- (void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContactProperty:(CNContactProperty *)contactProperty;

{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
    CNLabeledValue *phoneNumberValue = contactProperty.value;
    NSString *contactString = [phoneNumberValue valueForKey:@"_stringValue"];

    contactString = [contactString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    contactString = [contactString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; // This line of code is not working properly
    contactString = [contactString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    contactString = [contactString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    txtRecipient.text = contactString;
}
```

This is my code. I am using contactPicker to pick a contact from phonebook. Then I am storing it in to a string variable. After that I am removing dashes, brackets and spaces from string value by using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. Every thing is working fine except for this line:

```
contactString = [contactString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

After this line of code contactString remains the same i.e, spaces didn't get removed from the string. I also tried `componentsSeparatedByString` function but its returning only 1 character. i.e,

```
NSArray *components = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

components.length is returning 1.

Hope you understand my question. Is there any other way of removing spaces from a string? Any kind of help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like this is not a standard space.
Try this:

```
  NSMutableCharacterSet* set = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
  [set addCharactersInString:@"()-"];
  NSMutableString * contactString = [[phoneNumberValue valueForKey:@"_stringValue"] mutableCopy];
  NSRange range;
  while ((range = [contactString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set]).location!=NSNotFound) {
    [contactString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
  }
```